# Android Eclipse - Stop Garbage Collector for layout Design

Tags: java, android, eclipse, garbage-collection, heap-memory

Is there any way to stop the garbage collector while i am designing my layout?

My actual system only has 3gb ram and as soon as i try to develop/design on a layout my Java heap space explodes.

I already set the maximum heapsize which is possible on my system.

error report:

```
Problem Occured
fragment_xx.xml:
Java heap space
```

Comment: Why do you think stopping the Garbage Collector from running is going to remedy heap space problems?

Comment: i guessed :P is there a opportunity to stop increasing heap size as soon as i am working on the fragment layout design? And maybe instead of stopping the GC i should keep it permanently running to stay under the maximum of the heap volume...

Comment: The heap space can't expand beyond the size that you've defined with the `-Xmx` argument. There's no need to try and keep the GC running to stay under the maximum - the JVM guarantees that the GC **will** run prior to throwing an `OutOfMemoryError`, so if you're getting one then it usually boils down to one of two problems: either your heap space just isn't big enough, or there are some serious memory management problems within the application (such as not properly closing `Closeable` resources).

Comment: You should probably fix the errors in your app that cause this issue rather than find a way to circumvent the garbage collection.

Comment: Okay i`ll try to find the errors. Like i said it is a 3gb ram system and win xp with 32 bit running on it. On my win 7 64 bit system with 8 gb ram it works perfectly...i just thought there is a way to design the fragment without attaching ressources :P